# How can vector functions define coordinate systems?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, coordinate-systems

I was watching a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtEk1at3sVk) in which the professor states that by taking the derivative of a vector function, one can find the basis of the coordinate system being studied. My question is, how can a vector function define a coordinate system? Does it not need the coordinate system in the first place so that we can study it?

I know vectors are not the numerical representations we assign to them, they are geometric entities of their own, and a vector valued function goes around every point in a vector space and assigns it a vector, but how can this function work if its arguments are described by the coordinate system? What is the explanation that makes this seemingly circular logic go away?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't watch the video, just looked at a couple of stills in the middle, but it looks like what he's doing is taking coordinate functions for a manifold (in this case the manifold is just the plane and the coordinates are polar coordinates) and using them to give a basis for the tangent space to the manifold at a given point.

Since the tangent space to the plane at a point is a two-dimensional vector space looking very much like the plane itself, it's easy to get the two mixed up.  But they're fundamentally different sorts of things.